# read pdf with php and PDF2Text or pdf-to-text (spatie)

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-5, pdftotext

i´m traying to extract text from my PDF with class `PDF2Text` or s`patie/pdf-to-text` but i can´t to do... i´m traying first with:

**PDF2Text**

```
if($request->file('adjunto') != ""){

                $fileName = $request->file('adjunto')[0]->getClientOriginalName();

                $ext = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    
                $name = $fileName;
                $result = $request->file('adjunto')[0]->storeAs('importaciones', $name, 'public');
    
                $route =  public_path('storage/importaciones/'.$name);
    
            }else{
                return "Error al subir fichero, consulte al administrador del sistema";
            }

            if ($ext == "pdf" || $ext == "PDF"){
                $a = new PDF2Text();
                $a->setFilename($route);
                $a->decodePDF();
                echo $a->output();
            }else{
```

this else it´s for read CSV files. *This code in block if PDF* return empty result. And if i tray with

**spatie library**:

```
if($request->file('adjunto') != ""){

                $fileName = $request->file('adjunto')[0]->getClientOriginalName();

                $ext = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    
                $name = $fileName;
                $result = $request->file('adjunto')[0]->storeAs('importaciones', $name, 'public');
    
                $route =  public_path('storage/importaciones/'.$name);
    
            }else{
                return "Error al subir fichero, consulte al administrador del sistema";
            }

            if ($ext == "pdf" || $ext == "PDF"){
                $text = (new Pdf())
                        ->setPdf($route)
                        ->text();
                echo $text;
            }else{
```

return this:

```
Error Output:
================

    El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.
     {"userId":60,"exception":"[object] (Spatie\\PdfToText\\Exceptions\\CouldNotExtractText(code: 0): The command \"\"/usr/bin/pdftotext\" \"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\gdsRepository\\public\\storage/importaciones/VIZNAR.PDF\" -\" failed.
    
    Exit Code: 1(General error)
    
    Working directory: C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\gdsRepository\\public
    
    Output:
    ================
```

if i tray with `$fileName` not `$route`

return this: `local.ERROR: could not find or read pdf 'x.pdf'`  for my application i´m using laravel 5.6

mi PDF it´s:

[image]

i need 'nombre'(name), 'domicilio'(address), 'telefonos'(phone)

in this link, have pdf example:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/14uz4_sRphrOVvziv6n6_illb778WkETl/view?usp=sharing

Thanks for read and thanks for help me, please

searching in google i´m getting one solution for my problem and it´s:

```
PDF Parser
```

with this library -> `https://www.pdfparser.org/documentation` i´ve got read all my pdf file and this it´s result:

```
Código Nombre Domicilio Teléfonos Observacion
1740756 ESPIGARES CALVO MARIA LUISA CONSTITUCION 8 958 54 91 23
1769291 GOMEZ ESPIGARES ANGEL LUIS CONSTITUCION 9 958 54 31 04
1781409 JIMENEZ MORENO MARCO ANTONIO CORAZON DE JESUS 10 958 49 99 01
```

but now i need get only `nombre(name), domicilio(address), teléfonos(phone)`

how i can to do this?